# Cant render to ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im learning node.js and now I'm trying to write and read data to/from JSON. I was able to find out how to write data from form to JSON file and how to get them on front end. But now I have a problem when I post new data from form, site should render back to test.ejs with message "File uploaded". Instead of that I get Error "dataTest is not defined.

Here is my test.ejs code from views folder

```
<div class="container">

        <%= typeof msg != 'undefined' ? msg : '' %>
        <form action="test/send" method="post" role="form">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name" /><br>
            Lastname:<input type="text" name="lastname" /><br>
            Adress:<input type=="text" name="adress" /><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" >
    </form>

    <div class="users">
        <% dataTest.forEach(function(dat) { %>
            <p>
                <%= dat.name %>
                <%= dat.lastname %>
                <%= dat.adress %>
            </p>
        <% }); %>
    </div>
```

and my test.js code from routes folder

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var router = express.Router();

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

var dataTest = require('../data/dataTest.json');

// GET test page.
router.get('/', (req,res) => res.render('test', {dataTest: dataTest}));

// POST data to dataTest.json
router.post('/send', (req,res) => {
    var file = './data/dataTest.json';

    var name = req.body.name;
    var lastname = req.body.lastname;
    var adress = req.body.adress;

    var obj = { name: name,lastname: lastname,adress: adress };

// 1. Read the existing file
fs.readFile(file, (err, data) => {
    if (err && err.code === "ENOENT") {
        return fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify([obj]), error => console.error);
    }
    else if (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }    
    else {
        try {
            const fileData = JSON.parse(data);
            fileData.push(obj);
            return fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(fileData), error => console.error)
        } catch(exception) {
            console.error(exception);
        }
    }
});
res.render('test', {msg: 'File Uploaded!'});
})

module.exports = router;
```

Where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `dataTest` is not defined, you should probably define it:

```
res.render('test', {dataTest: [], msg: 'File Uploaded!'});
```

Comment: Thanks. This works, but when page is rendered i cant see new data until I refresh page. Is it possible to load new data without reloading page? Actually I noticed thad it redirects me to test/send where I dont see new data. Now I have to go back to test/ to see new data

Answer (score 0):

i guess this

```
var dataTest = require('../data/dataTest.json');
```

returns undefined which in return makes `dataTest` undefined here

```
res.render('test', {dataTest: dataTest}));
```

so i suggest you check `dataTest` contains a valid content. simply just do

```
console.log(dataTest);
```